# vb6 using a SUB as a PARAMETER in another SUB?

Tags: c#, vb6

Trying to upgrade this VB6 code to C# but I have trouble understanding or researching how this works:

```
Public Sub SetChannelIncludeStatus(blnChanIncluded() As Boolean, intMaxChans 
As Integer, strSlot As String)
```

How is it possible to include another sub like that as parameter? 
How do I do it in C#?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, if you just want this code converted to C# then this question is off topic as Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.  If you are asking how to pass a delegate to a method then you'll have to clarify your question.

Comment: Nope: `blnChanIncluded()` is an *array* of boolean not a method.

Comment: In C# this would be: `public void SetChannelIncludeStatus(bool[] blnChanIncluded, int intMaxChans, string strSlot)`. The square brackes make it clearer. Well to be exact, the parameters would be by `ref`. Maybe you should add a `ByVal` to all your parameters.

Comment: @AlexK thanks for that clarification lol. Kinda new to using VB6, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't passing a procedure - `blnChanIncluded()` is actually an **array**. VB6 array and function syntax is similar.